# What to replace -static-libgcc with when using clang?

Tags: gcc, clang, static-libraries, porting

I'm trying to port to Macintosh OSX where clang is provided instead of gcc.  When building on Linux with gcc, I pass `-static-libgcc` to gcc.

What is the nearest equivalent I might replace this option when using clang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this has already been sorted out, but for the sake of completeness, 
-- you cannot not link with system libraries statically on mac, till you do some extra work of compiling crt0.o.

So, simply remove this flag.

Please see

stackoverflow.com/questions/5259249/creating-static-mac-os-x-c-build

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html